# WebRTC-how to receive remote stream in Safari on IOS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I want to make a real-time video call. I use suggestion on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia. 
It works fine on desktop (CHROME,FIREFOX) and ANDROID but not on iOS.
When I make a call from DESKTOP (CHROME) to iOS (12.4.5). It has notification to accept "Access Camera & Microphone".When i click on Accept, it shows a camera sign on browser but have local stream and remote stream.
When i make a call from iOS to DESKTOP. Local stream is display on mobile but have no remote stream.
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I also have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with peerjs and cordova-plugin-iosrtc but in my case, the remote stream was never been shown on an ios device. 
The problem was in handling the incoming stream. Peerjs handles the stream with `call.on('stream', stream => { // do something with stream });` which doesn't work for some reason (not sure but I think cordova plugin uses onaddstream, and peerjs uses onaddtrak).

I have fixed my problem by adding `call.peerConnection.onaddstream = function (stream) { // do something with stream }`.

I know it not a direct answer to your problem, but it may help someone...